# How to get projection and selection attributes from an sql query?

Tags: python

I need to get the names of attributes that are projected and selected in an sql query and also the count of these attributes.

From query "SELECT R1.A,R1.C,R2.B,R2.D from R1,R2 where R1.A=R2.A"

I need to get the count of projected attributes from each table.
ie: from R1 it is A,c(count of projected attributes as 2) and from R2 it is B,D.

Also selected attributes from R1 as A(count of attributes as 1) and R2 as A(count as 1)
Can anyone suggest me a way to achieve this in python?

Comment: Simple : parse the SQL query into an appropriate parse tree, then navigate this parse tree to get the infos you need.

Comment: Try the `sqlparse` package http://sqlparse.readthedocs.io

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers could u pls explain it in detail.. i'm new to python

Comment: it worked... thanks